Npm run build/start do not get all pages
I have the following code of my routes in a react/vite app:
<Router>
   <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<LoginPage mensagemSucesso={mensagemSucesso} />} />
      <Route exact path="/criar-conta" element={<CriarConta onContaCriadaSucesso={(mensagem) => { handleRetornoSucesso(mensagem)}} />} />
      <Route exact path="/recuperar-senha" element={<RecuperarSenha onRecuperacaoSucesso={(mensagem) => { handleRetornoSucesso(mensagem)}} />} />
      <Route path="/redefinir-senha/:key" element={<RedefinirSenha onRedefinirSucesso={(mensagem) => { handleRetornoSucesso(mensagem)}} />} />
      <Route exact path="/principal" element={<AuthMiddleware><Principal /></AuthMiddleware>} />
   </Routes>
</Router>

All those pages are imported in the beginning of the file. When I run npm run dev, the URL "localhost:5173/redefinir-senha/code" works. But when I run npm run start, the same URL gets a NOT FOUND from the frontend and the console appear the message GET http://localhost:3000/redefinir-senha/code 404 (Not Found).
In package.json to check for npm run start and npm run dev:
"scripts": {
    "start": "vite build && serve dist",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  }

Am I missing something that I have to do to work in npm run start to make it work in production environment?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  . It's unknown what's "npm run start" in your case

I put the commands of the package.json to check over npm run dev and npm run start

You're supposed to serve an app with client-side routing with  a webserver that's configured for SPA, i.e. serves index.html on 404. "serve" doesn't do this

To make the node understand routes that work dynamically, like /redefinir-senha/123 and /redefinir-senha/abc, I had to install the express with npm install express, create a server.js file on root folder with the following code:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

// Servir arquivos estáticos da pasta 'build'
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Rotas para servir a aplicação React
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

// Rota para lidar com as rotas React que contêm parâmetros dinâmicos
app.get('/redefinir-senha/:key', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

// Lidar com todas as outras rotas, redirecionando para a página inicial
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
});

// Iniciar o servidor
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor Express iniciado na porta ${port}`);
});

Also, add one more script at the package.json file:
"server": "node server.js"

This way, the server worked and could get those routes dynamically. Otherwise, the npm run build only gets the routes that exists statically. For example, if have a Link element to /redefinir-senha/123, that element will be working, but if I had to access /redefinir-senha/abc, the pages would not found.
